# piping data from subprocess to thread process

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, subprocess

I would like to use the subprocess (and threading) module to:

1. call a program that will process a binary file into a human readable output
2. process the output of the subprocess
3. do 1 & 2 at the same time for two replicates (if possible)

Because this is genome scale data at nucleotide resolution, dependent on genome size. For real human data, writing the subprocess output to a temp file can cost 500GB of space, and I would like to avoid this if possible.

I have tried two strategies, one where the subprocess output is saved in a temporary file, and the other where I use the stdout=subprocess.PIPE option with Popen. Either way, this is my rate limiting step and becomes restrictive when I use real data sets.

With temp files using subprocess module only:

```
SC_paste_rep1 = subprocess.Popen(["bwtool","paste","typeA_rep1","typeB_rep1","-o=tmp_file_rep1.bg"])
SC_pasteM_rep2 = subprocess.Popen(["bwtool","paste","typeA_rep2","typeB_rep2","-o=tmp_file_rep2.bg"])

SC_paste_rep1.wait()
SC_paste_rep2.wait()
```

Then I iterate through each temp file, one after the other, and process the lines (using something that looks like the f() in the below chunk of code). When I time my script on a test set, I get:
   real 7m9.100s
   user 8m43.162s
   sys  0m21.572s

My second attempt avoids the temp file and utilizes subprocess and threading:

```
def struct_bind(input_pipe, output_pipe, calc_structScore):
        def f():
            try:
                DS_old_val = ''
                SS_old_val = ''
                old_chr = ''
                start_set = ''
                stop_set = ''
                for line in iter(input_pipe.readline, ''):
                    (out_line,start_set,stop_set,old_chr,DS_old_val,SS_old_val) = calc_structScore(line,start_set,stop_set,old_chr,DS_old_val,SS_old_val)
                    if out_line != "hold":
                        output_pipe.write(out_line)
            finally:
                try:
                    output_pipe.close()
                finally:
                    input_pipe.close()
        t = threading.Thread(target=f)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        return t

output_rep1_open = open("output_rep1.bw",'w')
output_rep2_open = open("output_rep2.bw",'w')

SC_paste_rep1 = subprocess.Popen(["bwtool","paste","typeA_rep1","typeB_rep1"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=-1)
SC_mod_rep1 = struct_bind(SC_paste_rep1.stdout,output_rep1_open,calc_structScore)

SC_paste_rep2 = subprocess.Popen(["bwtool","paste","typeA_rep2","typeB_rep2"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=-1)
SC_mod_rep2 = struct_bind(SC_paste_rep2.stdout,output_rep2_open,calc_structScore)

SC_mod_rep1.join()
SC_mod_rep2.join()
SC_paste_rep1.wait()
SC_paste_rep2.wait()
```

When I time this with bufsize=-1:
    real    11m59.916s
    user    15m15.790s
    sys 6m4.131s

And bufsize=0:
    real    25m11.939s
    user    26m11.768s
    sys 25m46.414s

On a real data set, using temp files I can get:
    real    151m3.040s
    user    172m4.584s
    sys 8m33.428s

and without I can get:
    real    248m52.712s
    user    301m30.378s
    sys 151m23.694s

What is wrong with my piping strategy that makes it 2x as fast to use a temp file, and what can I do to improve this? The speed gain when using the temp files especially surprising, considering I process the 2 one after the other.

Comment: Does it have to be Python? You can just do it on the command line.

Comment: I would like to try to keep this in Python. The code I posted is part of a larger script which I would like to keep as a single script. Is your thought to turn f() from struct_bind() into it's own widget and pipe the bwtool output into that?

Comment: I was thinking of a simple thing like "cmd1 file1 | cmd2", but you can do this:  os.system('cmd.exe /c start + cmd1 file1 | cmd2')

Comment: I thought that the subprocess module was designed to replace os.system() and also that invoking shell was something to avoid. That said, I will try this suggestion out, thank you. However, I'm still very interested in understanding how to get PIPE to work within python efficiently.